# Missing number, treated as zero with amsmath and calc

Tags: amsmath, counters, calculations

This simple code produces

```
"Missing number, treated as zero"
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{test}
\newcounter{testtwo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \addtocounter{test}{\value{testtwo}*\value{testtwo}}
\end{document}
```

In the following situations compiles good:

- Without `amsmath`
- When `calc` is loaded after `amsmath`
- using `\setcounter` instead of `\addtocounter`

What is happening here?

If a class loads `calc` and we need `amsmath`, what can we do? I know that a solution in this case would be loading `amsmath` before the class with `\RequirePackage`. It is possible another workaround between both `\usepackage`?

Comment: `calc` does some redefinitions in the `addtocounter` macro. Standard `addtocounter` strips down to a TeX `advance` which does not work with three tokens (value1 * value2).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, happy to see your real name again!

Comment: @karlkoeller: Yes, I am on the Dark Side again ;-) Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Both worked and was what I want. As a side question: loading `calc` after `amsmath` works as a "fix", but it breaks some functionality of `amsmath` for which its developers defined these macros  in that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quicker workaround, regardless which package is loaded first, is to use `\numexpr` from `e-tex` extensions (which should be available for basically any TeX distribution nowadays).

It expands the values of the calculation before it's advance by `\addtocounter`

In the following MWE the result is, as expected, `100`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{test}
\newcounter{testtwo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{testtwo}{10}

\addtocounter{test}{\numexpr\value{testtwo}*\value{testtwo}}

\thetest
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\numexpr` then you don't need `calc`...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Right. I kept it in order to `prove` that it works this way (regarding the loading order)

Answer (score 5):

Since `calc` redefines `\setcounter`, `\stepcounter` and `\addtocounter`, the only way you have if you want to keep your settings is to redeclare these definitions after loading `amsmath`.

That is, add the following lines in your preamble after `\usepackage{amsmath}`

```
\makeatletter
\def\setcounter#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}%
   {\calc@assign@count{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname}{#2}}}
  \def\addtocounter#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}%
    {\calc@assign@count{\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname}{#2}}}%
  \def\stepcounter#1{\@ifundefined {c@#1}%
    {\@nocounterr {#1}}%
    {\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname \@ne
    \begingroup
      \let\@elt\@stpelt \csname cl@#1\endcsname
    \endgroup}}%
\@ifpackageloaded{amstext}{%
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\stepcounter
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\iffirstchoice@\stepcounter{#1}\fi
 }
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\addtocounter
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter#\expandafter2\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\iffirstchoice@\addtocounter{#1}{#2}\fi
 }
}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{test}
\newcounter{testtwo}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\setcounter#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}%
   {\calc@assign@count{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname}{#2}}}
  \def\addtocounter#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}%
    {\calc@assign@count{\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname}{#2}}}%
  \def\stepcounter#1{\@ifundefined {c@#1}%
    {\@nocounterr {#1}}%
    {\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname \@ne
    \begingroup
      \let\@elt\@stpelt \csname cl@#1\endcsname
    \endgroup}}%
\@ifpackageloaded{amstext}{%
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\stepcounter
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\iffirstchoice@\stepcounter{#1}\fi
 }
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\addtocounter
    \expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter#\expandafter2\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\iffirstchoice@\addtocounter{#1}{#2}\fi
 }
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \setcounter{testtwo}{6}
 \addtocounter{test}{\value{testtwo}*\value{testtwo}}
 \the\value{test}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Very elaborate! I was too lazy to copy all the stuff to the MWE ;-)